# Mixture problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

A tank contains $100 gal$ of pure water initially. From t=0, a brine contains 4lb of salt per gallon flows into the tank at a rate of $5\frac{gal}{min}$. The mixture is kept uniform by stirring and the outflow of the liquid is slower that is $3\frac{gal}{min}$.

When there is $50 lb$ of salt in the tank

My attempt is:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=20-\frac{3x}{100+2t}$$

Solving it we have

$$x(100+2t)^{\frac{3}{2}}+4(100)^{\frac{5}{2}}=4(100+2t)^{\frac{5}{2}}$$

What I got is $2.59$ minutes but the book suggests $2.72$ minutes. I have tried but it seems not possible for me

Comment: Maybe I´m wrong but I have $t=2.595$ as well.

Comment: Ya. Me too. Could it be the answer is wrong? Lol.

Comment: I would say that the suggested solution is wrong. Maybe there will be another comment/answer with a different opinion. We will see.